# Files won't delete

Tags: php, ubuntu

I ran `chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/dev.example.com/public_html/uploads/` didn't work
Tried chmod 777 didn't work.

```
define('UPLOADPATH', "/srv/www/dev.example.com/public_html/uploads/members/");
$userId = 6;
$dir = UPLOADPATH . $userId;
rmdir($dir);
```

isn't removing the users folder(This runs to wipe out all their files, when deleting account).
also(To delete just one photo)

```
 $RemovePreview = UPLOADPATH . $userId. '/' . $file . '_preview.' . $image_ending;
                        if (file_exists($RemovePreview))
                        {
                            @unlink($RemovePreview);
                        }
```

file and image_ending are coming from my Database. Also won't delete the file.

I really don't know whats up. Not sure if this is a Php, Server or both issue?

Comment: "Didn't work" is a strange error message to get back from PHP. Is that really what it said?

Comment: No error. Maybe its in the error.log file tho. I'm gonna go look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your directory empty? The [Documentation to `rmdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) says that the directory needs to be empty; what you might be looking for is a recursive version of rmdir:

```
function rrmdir($dir)
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")
                    rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
                else
                    unlink($dir."/".$object);
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sucks `rmdir()` never got the recursive argument like `mkdir()` did.

Comment: Thank you! I found out why unlink wasn't working. Well it was working. I forgot that on my hosting plan i added a CDN. So the image was deleted on the server but when you viewed it, it showed up like it was there. I purge the cache on my CDN, and the image didn't show up! My old server didn't do this so i wasn't used to it. So i'll do whats in that function to delete a whole folder. Then both problems are solved!

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo when you try chown or chmod on files or directory you don't own.